# Почему неверный код работает без ошибок?

Tags: c++, функции, память, неопределённое-поведение

Почему приведенный код работает у меня без ошибок?

```
int* func() {
   int var = 100;
   return &var;
}


int main()
{
    int* ptr = func();
    cout << *ptr; // печатает 100, хотя здесь я ждал ошибки или неопределённого поведения, ведь var должна быть уже удалена к этому моменту
}
```

Я возвращаю адрес на локальную переменную `var`, которая должна была удалиться при выходе из `func()`, но я всё равно могу обратиться к ней (`cout << *ptr;`)

Comment: Может быть, это следствие оптимизации при компиляции? Учитывая, что функция предельно проста, и результат ее вызова известен на этапе компиляции, компилятор мог заменить тело функции main на *cout << 100*

Comment: поведение неопределенное после такого, поделай выделения памяти, удаления, перезатрется возможно  мусором после этого

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов в debug сборке не должно же быть никакой оптимизации

Comment: @zhukov, вроде бы не должно, но... Лично я не проверял, за ненадобностью лично для меня.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Общий принцип -

> Если вы переходите дорогу в неположенном месте, то это еще не значит, что вас обязательно должна сбить машина. А если не сбила - то это еще не значит, что можно переходить дорогу в неположенном месте...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int* func()
{
   int var = 100;
   return &var;
}

int z()
{
    int u[5] = { };
    return u[3];
}

int main()
{
    int* ptr = func();
    cout << *ptr << endl;
    cout << z() << endl;
    cout << *ptr << endl;
}
```

Компилируем VC+2017 с ключиком `/Od`, и получаем на выходе

```
100
0
1677336624
```

Просто у вас стек портится не мгновенно :)...

Answer (score 5):

Напечатать 100 - это один из множества вариантов неопределенного поведения.

Неопределенное поведение не тождественно ошибке.

Может быть ошибка, может быть то, что вы ожидали, а может и еще что-нибудь