# Почему массив корректно копируется, когда выделяю память через malloc размером 0 в C?

Tags: c, динамические-массивы, malloc

```
 int array1[100] = { 1, 2 , 3, 10, 1, 2 , 3, 10, 1, 2,
                    1, 2 , 3, 10, 1, 2 , 3, 10, 1, 2,
                    1, 2 , 3, 10, 1, 2 , 3, 10, 1, 2,
                    1, 2 , 3, 10, 1, 2 , 3, 10, 1, 2,
                    1, 2 , 3, 10, 1, 2 , 3, 10, 1, 2,
                    1, 2 , 3, 10, 1, 2 , 3, 10, 1, 2,
                    1, 2 , 3, 10, 1, 2 , 3, 10, 1, 2,
                    1, 2 , 3, 10, 1, 2 , 3, 10, 1, 2,
                    1, 2 , 3, 10, 1, 2 , 3, 10, 1, 2,
                    1, 2 , 3, 10, 1, 2 , 3, 10, 1, 2
};

int *array2;

array2 = malloc(0);

memcpy(array2, array1, 100 * sizeof(int));

for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    printf("%d\n", array2[i]);
}
```

Comment: Какая ОС? Какой компилятор? A вообще просто UB.

Comment: @ヒミコ Mac os, gcc

Comment: С отладчиком запустите, будет `SIGSEGV`.

Comment: Посмотрите [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1068166/195342) Главное - *Если вы переходите дорогу в неположенном месте, то это еще не значит, что вас обязательно должна сбить машина. А если не сбила - то это еще не значит, что можно переходить дорогу в неположенном месте...* Так сложились звезды, что вы смогли писать в эту память и *случайно* ничего не порушить. *Неопределенное поведение* - оно такое неопределенное... Так что не обольщайтесь - ваш массив *корректно* **не** копируется...

Comment: [Здесь](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) написано: _Если передаваемый размер равен нулю, поведение malloc определяется реализацией. Например, нулевой указатель может быть возвращен._ Может быть возвращен, но не обязательно.

Comment: @EOF есть ли исходник функции malloc?

Comment: У каждого компилятора, операционки и т.д. он свой.

Comment: А чего вы ожидали, неужели падения неба на землю? Вот попробуйте после такого вызова еще несколько раз вызвать malloc/free в разном порядке и я удивлюсь, если все не закончится SIGSEGV

Answer (score 0):

Как уже сказали в комментариях, вызов `malloc` с нулем в качестве аргумента вызвает поведение, определяемое реализацией:

> Если запрошена область памяти нулевого размера, поведение определяется
>   реализацией: вовращается или нулевой указатель, или какое-либо
>   ненулевое значение, которое не может быть использовано для доступа к
>   объекту.
>
> — C17 7.22.3/1

---

Не знаю, для чего это было нужно. Единственное, что приходит в голову — это выделение памяти в цикле:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < ARRLEN(sizes); ++i)
    objects[i] = malloc(sizes[i]);

for (size_t i = 0; i < ARRLEN(objects); ++i)
    free(objects);
```

Если бы `malloc(0)` вызывал неопределенное поведение, то нам пришлось вручную проверять, что ни один из элементов массива `sizes` не равен нулю. Но, так как стандарт позволят передавать `0` в `malloc`, можем об этом не беспокоится. Хотя, чтобы обратится к объекту, на который указывает возвращенный указатель все-равно нужно знать, был ли успешен вызов `malloc`.

Можно, конечно, хранить структуру (не обязательно в смысле `struct`) из указателя и булевой переменной, говорящей о валидности этого указателя:

```
struct {
    void *p;
    bool valid;
} pointer_t;
```

Не знаю, насколько подобная конструкция может быть полезна.

Comment: дело в том, что и подобный вызов array2 = malloc(2) спокойно реагирует. Тут дело в размере необходимой памяти. Я так понимаю либо  memcpy "добавляет" памяти место, либо в malloc выделяет больше памяти, чем нужно, поэтому в array2 вмещается array1. Хотелось бы узнать почему так.

Comment: @РобертГатри, да, конечно, реализации функции `malloc` зачастую выделяют больше памяти чем нужно, но это уже другой вопрос (и [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35110245/why-does-malloc-allocate-more-memory-spaces-than-i-ask-for) на него). Но это на самом деле не важно. Даже если будет выделено ровно 2 байта, то вы все еще *можете* записать 100 байт в по этому адресу, и это *может* работать, а *может* и нет. Наверняка все сработает, если запускать код по пятницам в полнолуние. Хотя, кто знает...

Comment: @РобертГатри, в общем, просите выделить 2 байта — так и используйте свои 2 байта.

Comment: https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/malloc/malloc.c.html#484

Comment: `malloc(0)` нужен для получения указателя, который гарантированно безопасно можно передать в `free()`

Comment: @avp, почему нельзя просто возвращать `NULL`? Его можно безопасно передавать в `free`.

Comment: @eanmos, для того, чтобы не путаться с ситуацией out of memory. / Кстати, [musl](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/malloc/malloc.c) по `malloc(0)` реально выделяет `4 * sizeof(size_t)` байт

Comment: @avp, как может быть out of memory, если мы запрашиваем 0 байт? Я имею в виду, можно просто вернуть `NULL` и все, к чему такие сложности?

Comment: @eanmos, здесь знаете, в общем случае не  знаете (например, читаете из файла размер), есть ли память определяете по результату вызова malloc. imho нормальное решение (зачем в manpage допускается возвращать 0 я не понимаю, наверное из исторических соображений, когда кто-то плохо подумал и реализовал возврат 0 по `malloc(0)`).